# Should the input data be normalized using keras pre-trained models

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I want to use a pre-trained [VGG16](https://keras.io/applications/#vgg16) in keras. My question is simple. Should I normalize the input image before predicting its label?

Comment: I tried this from scipy import ndimage from keras.preprocessing import image from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input im = scipy.misc.imread("cat_dog/validation/cats/cat.1362.jpg").astype(np.float32) im = scipy.misc.imresize(im, (224, 224)).astype(np.float32) im = np.expand_dims(im, axis=0) # im = preprocess_input(im) out = vgg16_model.predict(im) np.argmax(out) I tried to comment/uncomment the preprocess_input(...) and it apparently gave the same results and I think both sort of worked. The source for preprocess_input seemed to be at: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Very Deep Convolutional Networks for Large-Scale Image Recognition](https://www.arxiv-vanity.com/papers/1409.1556/), which is the paper that first presented VGG: "*...The only pre-processing we do is subtracting the mean RGB value, computed on the training set, from each pixel.*"- (Karen Simonyan, Andrew Zisserman).

I am certain that Keras provides a preprocess function based on the above mentioned principle.

Checkout: `tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input`

If it is in the TF version, its certainly in the other version.